# Which would be the best Neural Network Model to use for time series forecasting for this specific dataset?

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks

I have a set of `time series` data (60 monthly observations) of Room Nights sold for a particular hotel. I will be using `R` for my `time series` forecasting. The data does have seasonality and trends.
I would like to have a go at `Neural Network` for doing the forecast. I will of course compare the results with the more traditional `time series` forecasting methods used in `R`.
Which `Neural Network` do you think would mostly fit my data?

Comment: Make sure you do compare out-of-sample performance with "traditional forecasting models" (e.g. ARIMA, ETS, etc); you are in the small data regime where very simple models frequently outperform more complicated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an LSTM for your task. This type of recurrent network has demonstrated to be able to learn long-term dependencies as well as oscillatory behaviors, such as seasonality.

For reference you can take a look at [this](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) and [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/start-here/#lstm).

If you are using `R`, probably the easiest way you have to try them out is by using the [`R` interface to `Keras`](https://keras.rstudio.com).